# Insert multiple list items into another list

Tags: python, list, insert

I'm trying to insert list items from one list into another. I have found two solutions that work but they seem unnecessary complicated to me.

What I'm looking for is basically a list like this: `[1, 2, 4, 5, 3]`

```
someList = [1, 2, 3]
anotherList = [4, 5]
```

First solution:

```
for item in anotherList:
    someList.insert(2, item)
```

Second solution:

```
someList = someList[:2]+anotherList[:]+someList[2:]
```

My intuition was to use something like this but it's going to insert the list, not the list items.

```
someList.insert(2,anotherList)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a one line solution to this:

```
someList[2:2] = anotherList
```

This avoids the need to insert a `None` entry and yields the desired answer.

Answer (score 5):

Use a list slice to assign a list to a single item slice:

```
somelist.insert(2, None)
somelist[2:3] = anotherlist
```

*The first line creates a temporary entry that will be overwritten. The index 2 is where you want to insert your item*